# Getting PHPCI status on a github pull request?

Tags: php, github, continuous-integration, travis-ci, php-ci

I am wondering if it is possible to get a build status on github with PHPCI. Something similar to this but for PHPCI:

[image: http://s3itch.paperplanes.de/Fullscreen-13-2-20120827-214248.png]

The deployment server I am running PHPCI works fine but I would love to have this functionality. So far I can't seem to be able to find anything about it in the docs.